# Diffentiating a function f with respect to x

Tags: functions

I have a tabe y={10,20,30,40...}
and x={62,63,64,65...}

y is a function f and this function needs to be interpolated. How do I defferentiate the function f with respect to x?

Comment: Search the docs for `Interpolation[]`, `Transpose[]` and `Derivative[]`

Comment: Interpolated *how*? linear? quadratic? spline? something else?

Answer (score 3):

`Interpolation` in given range:

```
x = Range[62, 70];
y = Range[10, 90, 10];

f = Interpolation@Thread@{x, y};
f'[x0] /. x0 -> 65
```

> 10

```
dom = First@f["Domain"];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, First@dom, Last@dom}], 
 ListPlot[Thread@{x, y}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Interpolation to produce a usual polynomial:

```
g[xx_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[Thread@{x, y}, xx];
g'[xx]
```

Comment: The result I need is D[f,x]

Comment: I guess you already got it.. just type D[f[xx],xx]. or I missed something?

Comment: @EddyKe: funnypony already gave you `D[f, x]`; in Mathematica, you can enter a derivative using prime notation, so `f'[x0] /. x0 -> 65` gives you the derivative at 65.

Comment: @DrumpsterDoofus:  How do I get a derivative not just for a single point (65), but for all the points (62 to 70)?